# DC voltage source connected to an inductor is a current source?

Tags: boost, current-source

I was reading about voltage boost converter, where the DC voltage source in series with the inductor is mentioned as a current source. Why is this? Also, an inductor in series with a load resistor is modeled as a current sink. Any explanation to these two would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I was reading about voltage boost converter, where the DC voltage source in series with the inductor is mentioned as a current source. Why is this?

That sounds like an oversimplification.

A boost converter works in two phases. The first phase is when the switch is closed. The DC input is applied directly across the inductor, which causes its current to ramp up linearly.

The second phase is when the switch is open. Since the current in the inductor can't change instantaneously, you can think of it as a current source that's in series with the DC voltage source. The voltage at the open end of the inductor will rise until the current has someplace to go, usually through the diode and into the output capacitor.

> Also, an inductor in series with a load resistor is modeled as a current sink. Any explanation to these two would be appreciated.

I can only speculate about what this might have been referring to, but it might have something to do with how the current in the inductor ramps down during the "discharge' phase.